# Extracting the item from a DICTIONARY in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a dictionary that stores the sheet name and its number.

So the code is as:

```
Sub SetDiction()

Dim num as Excel.Range
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

For each wks in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
Set num = Nothing
Set num = wks.Range("SheetNumber")
If not(num is Nothing) Then
rModule.rDictionary.Add:=num.Value Item:=wks
End If
```

Next
   End Sub

Now am trying to get the wks name and put it in another worksheet.The code is:

```
Sub GetSheet()
Dim key as variant

For each key in rModule.rDictionary.Keys
With Sheet2
  .Cells(2,1).Value = rModule.rDictionary.Item(key)
End With
End Sub
```

It is giving me application defined or Object-defined error.
Can some one help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.Add` call is syntactically incorrect and you are adding the whole *worksheet* to the dictionary where presumably you just want to add the named range, change to:

```
rDictionary.Add num.Value, num
```

To add the name:

```
rDictionary.Add num.Value, wks.Name
```

Comment: num is an excel Range. I want the key as sheetnumber that is extracted from the range "SheetNumber" and added as key to dictionary. As an item corresponding to this key I want the worksheet name corresponding to that sheet number.

Comment: Add wks.Name for the name as a string

Comment: Alex am trying to assign this name to a worksheet using code: set sht.Name= rModule.rDictionary(key). Shows error as object or with block variable not defined. Can you tell me where am I going wrong  please?

Comment: Remove the `set`, its only use when assigning objects and `Name` is just  a string.

Comment: I tried doing it as wks.Name=rModule.rDictionary(key).It still shows the same error

Comment: Actually I want to get the value of a cell in that sheet. rmodule.rDictionary.Item(key).cells(Target.row, Target.column).value, but it doesnt work so i want to assign this name returned from item to a worksheet and then use that to get the cell value. Hope you get what am saying :O